# jQuery: How to select elements inside a div?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of `video objects` that are rendered in HTML as

```
   <div class="video">
        <p class='title'> {{ video.title }} </p>
        <p class='url'> {{ video.url }} </p> 
        <button class="btn btn-primary queue" href="#">queue</button>
    </div>
    <br />
```

**What I want?**

whenever I click on any video list, the title and url should be selected

I have a `jQuery` as

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.video', function(event) {
        var title = $(this).closest('.title');
        console.log(title);
        alert(title);
    });
});
```

When I see in firebug, the `console.log(title)` as `jQuery( )` in firebug, what is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`.closest()` goes up the parent chain.  If you want to search for child objects, use `.find()`.  Your code also makes it look like you want the contents of the div, not the jQuery object.  Combining those changes, you would get this:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.video', function(event) {
        var title = $(this).find('.title').html();
        console.log(title);
        alert(title);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.video', function(event) {
    var title = $(this).find('.title').html();
    console.log(title);
    alert(title);
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

`.closest('.title')` will go up the DOM hierarchy until it finds an element matching the selector. It will then return a jQuery object for that selector.

What you want to do instead is to traverse down the DOM hierarchy, e.g. using the [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method (to search for direct children) or the [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method (to search for children of children) and then retrieve their text using the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or their HTML content using the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)  method (instead of getting the jQuery object):

```
var title = $(this).children('.title').text();
```